# Can't launch my-weather-indicator

Tags: my-weather-indicator

I've installed my-weather-indicator software using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

However, I can't find it in my system. Waiting for your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the commands, and it's right there in the Unity Menu. Just type in 'weather' in the Unity Menu.
Click the big square button near the top left corner and type in 'weather' then click enter.

Comment: this is true for unity, but in other desktops the executable file may not be found by the launcher, as indicated in the other answer (it's in `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator` - that can be used as a command -, and sometimes  `usr/share/applications/my-weather-indicator.desktop` file is not created). In this case one should either create that desktop file there with that command, and/or add that command to the startup list

Answer (score 5):

It is located in `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/`. You can execute it in a terminal.:

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator
```

You could locate the binary for the `my-weather-indicator` package with:

```
dpkg -L my-weather-indicator | grep bin
```

Output:

```
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator
/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/dygraph-combined.js
```